# javascript fetch from intersect entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to write a javascript fetch for an intersect entity (created by N:N relationship between 2 entities).  I see C# samples everywhere but nothing for javascript.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Fetch is pretty universal between C# and JavaScript, so the same query should work in both.

http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2011/05/execute-fetch-from-javascript-in-crm-2011.html